# iOS app release bundle id

Tags: ios, app-store, release

If I have an app on the AppStore with the id as `com.mycompany.myapp`, if I delete the app from AppStore and also from ItunesConnect, will I be able then to upload a new (different) app with a different name but having the same bundle id?

Comment: why dont you just update the app version and reupload if you are willing to use same meta data

Comment: it's not the same app

Comment: If it's not the same app, why would you need to use the same bundle ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete your app, you can't restore it. The SKU or app name can't be reused in the same organization. If you've uploaded a binary or set up this app for the iAd App Network, your Bundle ID can't be reused.

Please [refer to this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html).

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.you have to use different bundle id.